# accessing a variable from outside the function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib
import rospy
import time
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry 

def position_callback(data):
    global q2
    q2=data.pose.pose.position.x
    q1=data.pose.pose.position.y
    q3=data.pose.pose.position.z


def position():      
    rospy.init_node('position', anonymous=True)  #initialize the node"
    rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, position_callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        position()
        print q2
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

the error i get is like this:

```
print q2
NameError: global name 'q2' is not defined
```

I defined `q2` as global variable already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring `q2` as a global variable does make the global variable exist.

Actually calling the function and execution of the assignment statement `q2 = ...` cause the creation of the variable. Until then, the code cannot access the variable.

`position` function does not call the `position_callback`, but pass it to `rospy.Subscriber` (which probably register the callback function, and not call it directly).

---

Initialize `q2` if you want to access the variable before it is set.

```
q2 = None

def position_callback(data):
    global q2
    q2 = data.pose.pose.position.x
    q1 = data.pose.pose.position.y
    q3 = data.pose.pose.position.z
```

Comment: no.i want to actually access the value..its not for printing..i want to use this value in some other function.

Comment: @RuthvikVaila, Initialize the variable `q2` to some value that represent null value if you want to access the variable before the callback is called. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `q2`. It cannot have a value. Try to define it in global scope - after the imports. Then call it iniside the function`position()`.