# how to declare variables in python in functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am newbie to python
i wrote a small function which is resulting in error
can you please let me know what is the mistake i am doing

```
def cost(input):

    output=input*2
    next=output*3
    return      output,next

print output
print next
```

Namerror name 'output' is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing a variable from outside the function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716133/accessing-a-variable-from-outside-the-function-in-python)

Comment: You haven't called the cost function yet. use `output,next = cost(10)` before printing output variable.

Answer (score 0):

Output is not defined since it is local to the function and the function hasn't even run. To get it globally, above `print output` you would put:

```
output, next = cost(1.12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function first. Both output and next are defined within the function and can not be accessed directly from outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
print output
```

There is no variable called `output` for python to display. The `output` variable you have is inside the function, which is not accessible outside.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the scope of the `output` and `next` variable is within the function, they cannot be referenced outside the function. If you want to print the result, just call the cost function in the print statement:

```
print cost(100)
```